# 'Predicate-logic' the best tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Having just been annoyed (ok, ok, I'm an old grouch) for the $n$-th time by seeing a question mis-tagged (indeed, mis-titled) [propositional-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-calculus), I've just realized there is no appropriate tag for questions that concern predicate logic, predicate calculus, quantificational logic, first-order logic (whatever you want to call it).

So, hopefully to get the ball rolling, I've retagged the last couple [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic). I think that's probably to be preferred to two of the other options ("calculus" is a bit old-school, "first-order logic" could be a bit restrictive). But maybe others would prefer "quantificational logic"? But we should surely encourage the use of one or the other and deprecate the use of "propositional-logic" for questions that essential concern the logic of quantifiers.

---

**Edit [Jan. $27$th A.K.]**:

Can we please make agree on some reasonable state, the current one is heading towards being very messy.

1. The main tag, [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) has over a thousand questions which makes sense to allow better fragmentation into specific parts.
2. We added [propositional-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propositional-calculus) quite some time ago, and it has 171 questions at time of this edit. This was also fine, because it seemed useful.
3. There are the barely used [higher-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-order-logic) and [modal-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-logic), and of course [fuzzy-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuzzy-logic). There are also the even scarcer tags, [nonclassical-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonclassical-logic) and [combinatory-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatory-logic).
4. Recently there has been a [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic) and [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic) which seem to me has having a lot of overlap, at least with respect to this site, and it's probably wise to merge them.
5. We also have [quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantifiers), which always baffled me. And the [boolean-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boolean-algebra) which takes some of the propositional calculus questions.

It seems that a good cleanup is in order. First order.

Comment: Apologies if so -- though it's one of those questions of nomenclature which can exercise people! So a question addressed to fellow logicians more widely than the (very?) few who read the meta questions.

Comment: There exists [tag:quantifiers] tag. Should it be synonym with the newly created [tag:predicate-logic]?

Comment: @MartinSleziak The quantifiers tag has no explication at the moment. But (to me) a question about "quantifiers" suggests something narrower in some ways, wider in others, i.e. a concern with *understanding* quantifiers in formal or informal languages. The suggested tag predicate-logic primarily concerns *derivations* in quantification theory.

Comment: Would [tag:predicate-logic] differ from [tag:first-order-logic] in some major way?  (They both appear to be quite new, so perhaps they should be merged.)

Comment: That's odd: I missed "first-order-logic" when I looked recently. Or is it *very* new?? I wouldn't object to merger -- except that "predicate-logic" perhaps usefully covers more (i.e. second-order logics too).

Comment: As far as I can tell, [tag:first-order-logic] was first used on the 5th version of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/276841/revisions) on 13 Jan.

Comment: Peter, I hijacked the thread instead of starting a near-duplicate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I very much agree with your sentiments

Comment: @Asaf: Here is an [older question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367/about-boolean-algebra-tag) about [tag:boolean-algebra] tag.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I like to search through logic questions to learn something new and I was lately surprised by lack of predicate calculus tag. I think this is so fundamental for logic that we should have this tag. According to Wikipedia those terms would be correct: predicate calculus, quantification theory.