# Is [tag:predicate-logic] a synonym for [tag:first-order-logic]?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

What is the difference between the tags [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic) and [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic)?

This question has been raised several times ([here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8267/predicate-logic-the-best-tag), [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/tag-about-first-order-logic) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/10971#10971)), and several users proposed in their comments to synonymize (or merge) them, but nobody concretely suggested them as synonymous on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

> Thus, I formally proposed to synonymize them [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/first-order-logic/synonyms), you can upvote or downvote as you prefer.

I'm aware that, from a theoretical point of view, the tag [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic) can cover more than [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic), since it can include also [second-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/second-order-logic) and [higher-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-order-logic), but concretely:

1. [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic) and [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic) have already a considerable overlap (at the time of this post, 619 questions contain both tags out of 2267 questions in [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic));
2. almost *all* the questions tagged with [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic) without [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic) could coherently and meaningfully be tagged with [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic);
3. the really few questions tagged with [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic) and that concern second or higher order logic could be tagged with [second-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/second-order-logic) or [higher-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/higher-order-logic), plus possibly [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic).

---

**Edit.** I relaunch this question I posted one year ago. To the present day, my proposal to make the tags [predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predicate-logic) and [first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-order-logic) synonyms reached a score of 3, so it needs just one more vote to be approved. Please, upvote (or downvote, if you don't agree) the tag synonym [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/first-order-logic/synonyms).

Comment: I was going to raise this, and I'm glad to see someone else taking interest in tagging.

Comment: My experience (both teaching and studying) is that predicate logic usually refers to the study of sentences and structures. First-order logic usually refers to the study of theories and models. While to the untrained eye this might seem the same, it's really not.

Comment: I guess my eye is untrained...

Comment: @AsafKaragila - In the domain of proof theory, predicate logic is most of the time a synonymous of first-order logic. Even on Wikipedia, predicate logic redirects to [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

Comment: @Andrés: In Beersheba we talked about predicate logic. We talked about formalizations, about this structure satisfies that formula with that assignment, and this formula implies that other one if and only if the material implication is logically valid. We didn't talk about theories, about models of theories, about completeness, etc. For me, that is the key difference between the two tags.

Comment: (@Asaf I understand what you are saying. I do not think this difference in usage is universal.)

Comment: @Andrés: I see. Well, then we agree. I guess it's just because this is how I was trained to think as a student and as a teacher, the distinction between the two tags is more natural to me.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: I know that you've been pinged by all my comments to Andrés, those are also for you (and anyone else weighing in on this conversation).

Comment: To me, "predicate logic" is applicable to higher-order logics as well as first-order logic. But I am fine with merging them, because I think that the higher-order logic tag is useful in almost every case that predicate-logic would not mean first-order-logic.